# Building AOSP based rom, error remove_packages already defined

Tags: android, build, android-source, android-rom

I've been bringing the rom Spark OS to the oneplus 6 got a build to boot and evertything works but there's apps I don't want to be included.
For example the stock clock app from aosp, I declared and included in the device/oneplus/sdm845/prebuilts/ android.mk and it did nothing.
Now I had to remove my remove_packages from the sdm845 device tree because the rom it self already has one.
How do I make it so that during the build a new clock app is installed and not the stock aosp one?

Answer (score 0):

Well I forgot to call the package in the common.mk in the device tree.